# How can I debug a wpad.dat file?

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer

I am having obscure problems within the JScript included in my browser proxy autoconfig file (aka PAC file). All this is taking place on Internet Explorer 7, so what I am dealing with is actually the so called wpad.dat file. From what I understand, the browser executes this file's FindProxyForURL function to determine which proxy to use based on host and URL.

So my question is: How can I put a debugger on my code? Ideally, I would like to start Internet Explorer and step through my wpad.dat code in Visual Studio 2010's debugger. Is that possible? If not, how do you folks debug wpad.dat files?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: For what it's worth, I resorted to a combination of alert(); and Wireshark.

Answer (score 2):

I use `pactester` to evaluate which proxy will be used for a certain URL:

http://code.google.com/p/pactester/